# angular 5 noty and AOT

Tags: angular, noty

I'm using noty (https://ned.im/noty) with angular 5.2.9 this way:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import Noty = require('noty');

@Injectable()
export class NotificationService {
    private noty(options) {
        return new Noty(options).show();
    }
    ...
}
```

and works fine.

but when I'm building with AOT (`npm run build:aot`) I get:

```
ERROR in src/app/sys/util/notification.service.ts(2,1): error TS1202:  
Import assignment cannot be used when targeting ECMAScript modules.  
Consider using 'import * as ns from "mod"', 'import {a} from "mod"', 'import d from "mod"', or another module format instead.
```

It's a project based on https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-starter.
When using `import Noty from 'noty';` the AOT build is fine but when running `npm run server` I get `ERROR TypeError: noty_1.default is not a constructor`.

node_modules/noty/index.d.ts starts with:

```
declare module 'noty' {
    export = Noty;
}

declare class Noty {
    constructor(options?: Noty.Options);
...
```

How should I solve this?

Comment: It says it right in the error: `import * as Noty from 'noty'`. Then try new `Noty.Noty(...)`, yes, odd syntax.

Comment: I tried with `npm run server` and I get: `ERROR in src/app/sys/util/notification.service.ts(24,21): error TS2339: Property 'Noty' does not exist on type 'typeof Noty'.`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that is working this way:

```
/// <reference path="../../../../node_modules/noty/index.d.ts" />

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import Noty = require('noty');

@Injectable()
export class NotificationService {
    private noty(options) {
        return new Noty(options).show();
    }
    ...
}
```

Because *noty* does not have the *d.ts* placed into node_modules/@types/... then I guess I have to manually reference it.

PS: also set `"no-reference": false` rule in *tsling.json* otherwise will mark the reference as an error